# What number I'm able to use to notify about haproxy issue?

Tags: haproxy

I have task to monitor Haproxy problems, and one of them is disappearing the field I recently used to get value from `show stat` output.

Firstly I've wanted to output -1 if there's no field that recently have returned values, but then I saw that `show stat` has -1 in its own output and that value means something.

What value instead I can use to report issues with haproxy?

Comment: What is this about? What field? Which values?

Comment: @NikitaKipriyanov
Field is `pxname` - I mean there that monitoring failed while one of a proxy dissappeared. And negative values of `rate_max` and `check_status`.

Comment: Check this https://github.com/DataDog/the-monitor/blob/master/haproxy/monitoring_haproxy_performance_metrics.md

Comment: @Turdie There're no metrics I'm searching for

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.